# Track Custom ActivitySource with Application Insights

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I am trying to get application insights to pick up on custom `ActivitySource` in a library, however the documentation is unclear on how to achieve this.

Currently I have the following:

```
...
public static readonly ActivitySource Source = new ActivitySource("MyCompany.Library");
...
```

In the library it is used like this:

```
using(var activity = Source.StartActivity("Action"))
{
   ...
}
```

And in my startup I've added the following:

```
services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>(
    (m, o) => m.IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities.Add("MyCompany.Library")
);

services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
```

However, these activities are not being picked up by application insights.
Is there something else required to make application insights aware of these activities ?

I'd rather not 'pollute' these libraries with application insights code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ApplicationInsights SDKs does not support reporting telemetry from custom `ActivitySource`.

There is a preview version which supports ActivitySource based telemetry. (Its called OpenTelemetry AzureMonitorExporter)
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=net

Answer (score -4):

Follow the below steps to operate:

1. Add the [OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console/) NuGet package.

**`dotnet add package OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console`**

2. Update Program.cs with additional OpenTelemetry using directives

   `using OpenTelemetry;`

   ```
    using OpenTelemetry.Resources;

    using OpenTelemetry.Trace;

    using System;

    using System.Diagnostics;

    using System.Threading.Tasks;
   ```
3. Update Main() to create the OpenTelemetry TracerProvider:

   public static async Task Main()
   {

   ```
            using var tracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
                .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("MySample"))

                .AddSource("Sample.DistributedTracing")
                .AddConsoleExporter()
                .Build();

            await DoSomeWork();
            Console.WriteLine("Example work done");
        }
   ```

Now the app collects distributed trace information and displays it to the console:

```
> dotnet run
```

You will get the result required.

Follow the below link for further reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/distributed-tracing-collection-walkthroughs

Comment: The question is about sending telemetry to ApplicationInsights. How does Console exporter help?